# Sencha Touch Error: Cannot read property 'dom' of null

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Debugging some Sencha Touch 2 code and I've boiled it down to this.  Why doesn't this work?  More importantly, why shouldn't it?  Clearly view, listOne, and listTwo are all in scope, but tapping listOne item, then going back, then tapping listOne item a second time results in an error.  Does Navigation View delete references when it goes back?

```
var view = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView', {
    xtype:'myview',
    fullscreen: true
});

var listTwo = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    store: {
        fields: ['name'],
        data: [
            {name: 'Doeth'},
            {name: 'Smith'},
            {name: 'Johnson'},
            {name: 'Stevens'}
        ]
    },
    itemTpl: '{name}'
});


var listOne = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    store: {
        fields: ['name'],
        data: [
            {name: 'Cowper'},
            {name: 'Everett'},
            {name: 'University'},
            {name: 'Forest'}
        ]
    },
    itemTpl: '{name}',
    listeners: {
       itemtap: function (me, index, target, record, e, eOpts ){
           view.push(listTwo);
        }
    }
});

Ext.Viewport.add(view);
view.push(listOne);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took a look at Sencha's source code and I confirm this is expected behaviour:
`Ext.NavigationView`, upon pressing **back** button calls its `pop()` method.
This, in turn, calls `remove()` on the NavigationView with the active view as argument. `remove()` is inherited from `Ext.Container`, and can optionally destroy the object. By default `autoDestroy` config is true, and this explains what's happening.

Set `autoDestroy` to false on the Navigation View to fix the error.

[Sencha fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#bZ6rT)

[Navigation View](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/source/View2.html#Ext-navigation-View)

[Container](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container)

Comment: these seems like very strange behaviour.  Certainly not what I would expect.  So by default they destroy the view, only to rebuild it again (in the case of nested lists) for example... thanks for the insight.

Comment: It makes sense, this way you save memory instead of keeping the view allocated but not used. Of course it is always a matter of finding the tradeoff between computation time to destroy/create views and loss of performance due to high memory usage.

Comment: It would make sense if it didn't cause an error.  This is the part that seems incorrect.